# How to implement "Add to favorites" function in android listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, asynchronous

I load data from internet to build the listview, and put a star icon for each row. If user checked the star, I would save the entire row data into sqllite databse.

My question is that how can I know if one item has been added to favorites before to mark or not to mark  the star checkbox. I know the database query is expensive and I can not do it in UI thread.

Just create an asynctask for each "getView" function to load the "favourites" data (if user fling too fast, there will be many asynctask pending) or do I have some other good options, or any 3rd lib for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i get my own answer, I get 10 items each time from internet, and then check the 10 items in database, assign "fav" value in all items, that works well.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, there's no reason you can't do a single query for favorites and pass that to a custom `Adapter` that also uses the internet data. Then in `getView` you can check to see if the current item is in the favorites.

Without seeing some code, it's hard to be more specific. Also, what's appropriate is going to depend on how many data items you are processing.